# Implementing method instrumentation using bytebuddy

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

We are trying to build a javaagent for instrumenting classes using ByteBuddy. We have a javassist implementation that does not work well with Mockito, and therefore moving to ByteBuddy for instrumentation.

Using the DynamicType$Builder, we need to instrument methods of a selected class, depending on whether the method is a constructor, class initializer, or any other.

In addition, the beforeMethod interceptor method has an argument that needs to be generated uniquely for every method. The afterMethod interceptor method is a zero argument method. So, we need to:

1. Create one MethodCall instance per instrumented method, to be used for method entry.
2. Create one MethodCall instance common to all instrumented methods, to be used for method exit.

The method calls are something like this:

```
        private static MethodCall getInsertBefore(Method method) {
            //construct a murmur32 hash using the method's class name, name, and signature.
            int murmur32Hash = ...;
            return MethodCall.invoke(named("beforeMethod"))
                    .on(SomeClass.class)
                    .withReference(murmur32Hash);
        }
        private static MethodCall getInsertAfter() {
            return MethodCall.invoke(named("afterMethod")).on(SomeClass.class); 
        }
```

The class with annotations:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void beforeMethod(int murmur32HashCode) {
        /*murmur32HashCode is generated during transformation and not selected from argument list*/
        ...
    }
    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void afterMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Using DynamicType$Builder, is there any way we can visit all declared methods, and for each method, create the above mentioned MethodCall instances to be invoked before and after for the method?

Javassist provided a intuitive way to do this. For ByteBuddy, in almost all examples I could find on net, the interception involves specifying a class with annotated methods, with arguments for the annotated methods selected from the invocation of the method being instrumented (no new generated values).

I went through the ByteBuddy code and it seems to be doable with MethodVisitor class, though I got lost trying to understand the code sequence.

---

Found that if we use custom mappings, we can specify a custom value for annotations which can be referred in the interceptors.
However, it cannot be used to set a custom value per instrumented method.
Maybe, there is no easy way to do it using ByteBuddy, and I need to add a constant per method, and inject byte code to refer to it.

Comment: This seems close to what I want but could not understand what is being done & need some more elaboration..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585748/pass-argument-to-bytebuddy-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered by the author of the library in this post.

[How to pass variables to advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951575/how-to-pass-variables-to-advice)

Instead of application of custom mapping at type level, I had to iterate over every method and apply the custom mapping for each method.

Question also posted here (and answered by the library's author):
https://groups.google.com/g/byte-buddy/c/lO7yqEAyEKE